# iOS background Audio Stream (m3u) doesn't work on device (but does in simulator)

Tags: ios, audio, background, m3u

I have a UIWebView that loads a m3u from a url:

```
NSString *url = @"http://141.217.20.38:8000/live.m3u";
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.url]]];
```

followed by:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier newTaskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
newTaskId = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:NULL];
```

This works on the simulator, but when I install it on a device (iPhone 5) via Xcode (with a development provisioning profile) the audio won't play in the background.

I'm not sure what I've missed, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it looks like an AVSession also needs to be created. I added the following code, and it now works on the device the same as in the simulator

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
BOOL ok;
NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
ok = [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                         error:&setCategoryError];
if (!ok) {
    NSLog(@"%s setCategoryError=%@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, setCategoryError);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` is for executing a lengthy task, not for keeping you app running in the background.

You need to register your apps background mode in `info.plist` set the background mode(`UIBackgroundModes`) to `audio`. As descripted in the [App States and Multitasking](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)

Comment: I have App plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay set in Required Background Modes.

Comment: There is no [`UIBackgroundModes`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22) AirPlay, you options are `audio`, `location`, `voip`, `fetch`, `remote-notification`, `newsstand-content`, `external-accessory`, `bluetooth-central` and `bluetooth-peripheral`.

Comment: I'm assuming this was set by Xcode after checking the "Audio and Airplay" Checkbox under Background Modes:

[Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hax1ucr28wmkqt5/Screenshot%202014-05-01%2010.57.01.png)

Comment: I added Audio to the list, and I still get the same behavior: Background audio works in the simulator, but not on a device.

Comment: The actual content of the `info.plist` is

`<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
 <array>
  <string>audio</string>
  <string>remote-notification</string>
 </array>`